# Almost each IF in the code is being accessed ignoring the statement specified in Python

Tags: python

This code is supposed to accept ids that either have 7 or 9 digits. No letters included but - can be included.

- If the id is 7 digits in can either be this format: 1-234-334 or 1123123
- If the id is 8 digits in can either be this format: 1-123-1234 or 11231234
- If the is is 9 digits in can either be this format: 1-1234-1234 or 112341234
- Also the second and third segment can't contain only 0s.

This is supposed to read a file with IDS and then generate another one with the ID and specifying if its correct or not.
Considering this, I've made this code in python like this.

```
w= open("VerifyingIds.txt","w+")


with open('Rejected.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        chars = []
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        for c in line:
            chars.append(c)

        #print(len(chars))
        print(str(chars))
        if any(char.isdigit() for string in chars for char in string):
            print(line + " no letters")
            if "-" in chars or len(chars) == 9 or 1 <= int(chars[0]) <= 9 or int(chars[2]) != 0 or int(
                    chars[3]) != 0 or int(chars[4]) != 0 or int(chars[6]) != 0 or int(
                chars[7]) != 0 or int(chars[8]) != 0:
                print("correct with 7 digits and - " + line)
                w.write(line + " ID correct1" + '\n')

            if "-" in chars or len(chars) == 10 or 1 <= int(chars[0]) <= 9 or int(chars[2]) != 0 or int(
                    chars[3]) != 0 or int(chars[4]) != 0 or int(chars[6]) != 0 or int(
                chars[7]) != 0 or int(chars[8]) != 0 or int(chars[9]) != 0:
                print("correct with 8 digits and - " + line)
                w.write(line + " ID correct2" + '\n')

            if "-" in chars or len(chars) == 11 or 1 <= int(chars[0]) <= 9 or int(chars[2]) != 0 or int(
                    chars[3]) != 0 or int(chars[4]) != 0 or int(chars[5]) != 0 or int(
                chars[7]) != 0 or int(chars[8]) != 0 or int(chars[9]) != 0 or int(chars[10]) != 0:
                print("correct with 9 digits and - " + line)
                w.write(line + " ID correct3" + '\n')

            if len(chars) == 7 or 1 <= int(chars[0]) <= 9 or int(chars[1]) != 0 or int(chars[2]) != 0 or int(
                    chars[3]) != 0 or int(chars[4]) != 0 or int(
                chars[5]) != 0 or int(chars[6]) != 0:
                print("correct with 7 digits and no - " + line)
                w.write(line + " ID correct4" + '\n')

            if len(chars) == 8 or 1 <= int(chars[0]) <= 9 or int(chars[1]) != 0 or int(chars[2]) != 0 or int(
                    chars[3]) != 0 or int(chars[4]) != 0 or int(
                chars[5]) != 0 or int(chars[6]) != 0 or int(chars[7]) != 0:
                print("correct with 8 digits and no - " + line)
                w.write(line + " ID correct5" + '\n')

            if len(chars) == 9 or 1 <= int(chars[0]) <= 9 or int(chars[1]) != 0 or int(chars[2]) != 0 or int(
                    chars[3]) != 0 or int(chars[4]) != 0 or int(
                chars[5]) != 0 or int(chars[6]) != 0 or int(chars[7]) != 0 or int(chars[8]) != 0:
                print("correct with 9 digits and no - " + line)
                w.write(line + " ID correct6" + '\n')
            else:
                print(line + "ID Incorrect7")
                w.write(line + " ID incorrect7" + '\n')

        if any(char.isalpha() for string in chars for char in string):
            print(line + " ID with letters")
            w.write(line + " ID incorrect8" + '\n')
```

When opening the file it can either be Accepted.txt (which includes the IDs that have to be accepted) and another one containing rejected ones.

[When I generate the VeryfyingIds.txt with the Rejected IDs I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrM3J.png)
Why is it writing in the file 6 times? I only have each rejected ID once but this repeats the id in the file and writes its correct (when its incorrect) with each time entering a different if.

Comment: Maybe you are using `or` when you actually mean `and` in your checks?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `or` and not `and`? `("-" in "1-234-456") or False
 ----> True`. Also: this is exactly the kind of problem that is usually easily solved using regular expressions...

Comment: This seems like a job for regular expressions (except maybe the "all zeros" part, for which it might be easier to add a separate check afterwards).

Comment: @Thomas You can handle that easily using lookaheads: `(?!000)\d{3}`. Also: the check that the second group must be shorter or equal than the last can be done with the `(?(id/name)yes_regex|no_regex)` syntax with something like `(?:(?P<second_4>\d{4})|\d{3})-(?(second_4)\d{4}|\d{3,4})` Or you just repeat the whole thing: `(\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{3}-\d{3,4})`

Comment: Can you please show us the structure of the Rejected.txt file?

Comment: [Example regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/mkzBBk/1).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `or` instead of `and`. By the way, [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) can help you a lot with this task:

```
import re

code = "100011234"

match_7 = re.match(r"^\d(-{0,1})(?!0{3})\d{3}\1(?!0{3})\d{3}$", code)
match_8 = re.match(r"^\d(-{0,1})(?!0{3})\d{3}\1(?!0{4})\d{4}$", code)
match_9 = re.match(r"^\d(-{0,1})(?!0{4})\d{4}\1(?!0{4})\d{4}$", code)

if match_7:
    print("correct code 7!")
elif match_8:
    print("correct code 8!")
elif match_9:
    print("correct code 9!")
else:
    print("wrong code!")
```

**output:**

> correct code 9!

RegEx (regular expressions) analyze our string, and see if the string matches what we want. This is what we want (in english, i.e. `match_7`):

```
# from the start of the string
# one digit
# one or zero dash
# 3 digits, not all 0's
# one or zero dash (depending on previous dash)
# 3 digits, not all 0's
# end of the string

# note that we are not specifying the length of the string, but we are defining how many digits we do expect and the start and the end of the string
```

And here is what our RegExs are doing:

```
match_7 = re.match(r"^\d(-{0,1})(?!0{3})\d{3}\1(?!0{3})\d{3}$", code)
# ^ = Start of the string
# \d = one digit
# (-{0,1}) = zero or one dash, the parenthesis define this match as 'group 1'
# (?!0{3}) = this point cant be followed by 3 0's
# \d{3} = 3 digits
# \1 = same match as 'group 1' (if group 1 matched 1 dash, expect 1 dash, if matched 0 dashes, expect 0 dashes)
# (?!0{3}) = this point cant be followed by 3 0's
# \d{3} = 3 digits
# $ = end of string
```

with this description, you can understand what `match_8` and `match_9` are describing